# I need to activate the main window of my only_one_instance wpf app when another app process is fired?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a Dictionary WPF APP which I Linked It with the hot key (Alt + A) this app checks on its window_activated event the Clipboard for copied text and immediately translates it.

now when the user hits the hot key (Alt + A) a new instance of the application is created so i decided to limit it to only one instance and i managed to do so but here is the problem

The user hits (Alt + A) the new instance is aborted but the previously existing one is running but i can't get the window to be activated here is the code i wrote

> ```
>   /// <summary>
>     /// Application Entry Point.
>     /// </summary>
>     [STAThread]
>     [DebuggerNonUserCode]
>     [GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
>     public static void Main()
>     {
>         // Get Reference to the current Process
>         var thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
>         // Check how many total processes have the same name as the current one
>         if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
>         {
>             // the new application instance.
>             Application.Current.Shutdown();
>             foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName))
>             {
>                 if(process.Id != thisProc.Id)
>                 {
>                     // here i need to activate the main window of my one instance app.
>                 }                        
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>         var app = new App();
>         app.InitializeComponent();
>         app.Run();
>     }
> ```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution after a great effort of searching and here is the code that worked for me

known that i am using the mui project on wpf.

> ```
>   public static class Win32 
>     {
>     //Import the FindWindow API to find our window
>     [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
>     private static extern IntPtr FindWindowNative(string className, string windowName);
>     //Import the SetForeground API to activate it
>     [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
>     private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindowNative(IntPtr hWnd);
>     public static IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName)
>     {
>         return FindWindowNative(className, windowName);
>     }
>     public static IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
>     {
>         return SetForegroundWindowNative(hWnd);
>     }
> }
> ```

```
internal class Program : Application
{
    private static void Activate(string title)
    {
        //Find the window, using the Window Title
        IntPtr hWnd = Win32.FindWindow(null, title);
        if (hWnd.ToInt32() > 0) //If found
        {
            Win32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //Activate it
        }
    }

    [STAThread]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [GeneratedCode("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get Reference to the current Process
        var thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        // Check how many total processes have the same name as the current one
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length > 1)
        {
            Activate("active dictionary");
            Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }
        var app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```